# Thread to ask for new tasks from executorservice

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I currently have the main method which collects tasks. After the tasks are collected, the `ExecutorService` is being called with fixed thread pool size. The tasks are iterated and submitted to the executor.

But I need to refresh the tasks and if there is any new tasks available I am adding it to the executor. But if one of the thread is free without any tasks to be allocated from the queue, I want that thread to manually notify my main thread to refresh the events and submit to executor even before the manual refresh is happening from my end. How can i achieve this. Thanks

Sample Code

```
public class Sample{
   Map<String, List<Integer>> tasks;
   ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
     tasks = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>());
     tasks =  Tasks.refresh(); //This will get me a new set of data to be processed
     invokeexecutor();
   }
   public void invokeexecutor(){
      for(String key: tasks.keyset())
      {
       executor.submit(new TaskRunnable(tasks.get(key));
      }
      tasks.clear(); //Remove the allocated tasks from the collection
   }
}

public class TaskRunnable implements Runnable{
   public void run(){
        //Do some logic
   }
}
```

In this case I want my data in the tasks to be continuously refreshed after 10 seconds lets say or if any of the executor thread is free this refresh must happen and a new runnable mus tbe assinged to the thread.

Comment: How does the main thread exactly work? Could you show some code?

Comment: Are you asking for the ExecutorService to notify you when it runs out of work to do?

Comment: I want the thread to notify my main thread for gettign new events and submit to the executor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to override [afterExecute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) method in ThreadPoolExecutor. It is called when a thread in a pool executed a task.

```
class MyThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    public MyThreadPoolExecutor {
        super(/*Call one of TheadPoolExecutor constructors*/)
    }

    protected afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        // Notify main thread here
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to access methods available in the main thread to refresh my tasks. That method is not visibile to my threads or my executor as of now.

Comment: You can add a constructor to MyThreadPoolExecutor, like MyThreadPoolExecutor(MainThread mainThread) to get access to methods that you need. Just store mainThread to a private field and use it when you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. Ill try this as well.

Comment: Beware that afterExecute is executed in a thread that finished a particular task, so you may need to have additional synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

> But if one of the thread is free without any tasks to be allocated from the queue, I want that thread to manually notify my main thread to refresh the events and submit to executor even before the manual refresh is happening from my end. How can i achieve this.

There are a couple of ways you can achieve this easily.  One way is to create the `ThreadPoolExecutor' yourself.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 2, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                             new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

Then have a polling thread that watches the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class to determine if there are any free threads.  Something like:

```
 while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
     // sleep a bit
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     if (executor.getActiveCount() < 2) {
        // add tasks here
     }
 }
```

A polling thread is a bit gross however.  Another idea which is a bit simpler would be to use a fixed size queue of tasks and then always be trying to add the tasks to the list.  This will block if the queue is full.  Something like:

```
// create a limited blocking queue
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 2, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                             new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10));
 while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
     // add tasks here which will block if too many in the queue
 }
```

Comment: Good to have you back!

Comment: The first approach was what I am putting as of now. Thanks